# nottagged parameter not documented

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

It appears that the /questions method still takes the nottagged which specifies a list of tags to exclude questions by but this parameter is not mentioned in the documentation. Is this parameter officially supported?

Comment: ++ interesting. /questions:tagged is an all inclusive param, so one would assume that nottagged would be all exclusive, while /search tagged and nottagged are selective. can't come up with a story for it but seems there should be one.

Comment: uhm, i don't get it.. http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions?tagged=curl&nottagged=php5 returns questions tagged php5

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't.  For that matter, I don't recall `/questions` ever taking `nottagged`.

The API just doesn't reject URLs with extraneous parameters.

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/stats?unicorns=yes+please

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a wild swing at this one and say that unspecified params are ignored.